# Array with Dictionary in c# using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key as integer type and  value as string type

Key    - value

1     -     "A"

2     -     "B"

3      -     "c"

4       -    "D"

5        -   "E"

and i have a array of string type

{"A","D","E"}

Now i want to match dictionary and array to produce the below output with dictionary key

1:true 4:true 5:true

In the above output integer indicates dictionary key saying value "A" is matched in array ie:- 1=true

Comment: If you search the dictionary using the strings? why int is the key?

Comment: is your dictionary key and array index both similar for comparision?

Comment: because if a string is matched in array then its key should be the output

Comment: @Mak no the dictionary key and array index will not be the same

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is a problem, not a question. Please show what you've tried. Otherwise, it sounds like you're asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `join` to find the matches:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{ 
    {1, "A"},
    {2, "B"},
    {3, "c"},
    {4, "D"},
    {5, "E"},
};

string[] values = new [] {"A","D","E"};

var query = 
    from kvp in dict
    join s in values on kvp.Value equals s
    select new {kvp.Key, Found = true};
```

You could also use `where values.Contains(kvp.Value)` instead of a join, but that will search the array each time, while the join will create lookups which will be searched more efficiently.  For the size of the data you posted, there probably isn't much performance gain, but for large collections it could be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this works fine with `LINK` :

```
 public List<string> liste = new List<string> { "A", "D", "E" };
            public Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>   
            {  
            {1, "A"},
            {2, "B"},
            {3, "c"},
            {4, "D"},
            {5, "E"},
            };

             private void TriCustomer()
             {
                var query =  from x in dic
                             join y in liste on x.Value equals y
                             select new { x.Key, IsTrue = true };
    // check here 
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.Key + " " + item.IsTrue);
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lookup function (either a local `Func`, or a class method), e.g.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{ {1,"A"},{2,"B"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "D"}, {5, "E"} };
var magicChars = new[]{"A", "D", "E"};

Func<int, bool> isMagicChar = n => dictionary.ContainsKey(n) 
                           && magicChars.Contains(dictionary[n]);
```

With some tests:

```
 Assert.IsTrue(isMagicChar(1));
 Assert.IsFalse(isMagicChar(2));
 Assert.IsTrue(isMagicChar(4));
 Assert.IsTrue(isMagicChar(5));
 Assert.IsFalse(isMagicChar(1232));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(){{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}};
var strArray = new[] { "A", "D", "E" };

var result = from item in dictionary
            select new {key = d.Key, value = strArray.Contains(d.Value)};
```

Hope this helps.