# My question is about comparing List<string> with Dictionary <string, List<string>> using C# linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have referred the below link in stack-overflow for my requirement which provide the matching key and Boolean results.I need the result of keys and values from the dictionary which matches with list of string.

Referred Link below:
[Array with Dictionary in c# using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167347/array-with-dictionary-in-c-sharp-using-linq)

The example is provided in the same link above. Any how I will provide the same below

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, <string>>
{ 
    {1, new List<string>(){"A","B"}},
    {2, new List<string>(){"C","D"}},
    {3, new List<string>(){"G","H"}},
    {4, new List<string>(){"E","F"}},
    {5, new List<string>(){"I","J"}},
};

string[] values = new [] 
{
    "A", "D", "E"
};

var result = 
  from kvp in dict
  join s in values on kvp.Value equals s
select new {kvp.Key, Found = true};
```

What I tried is below:

```
var result = dict
  .Select(x => new { 
     keys = x.Key, 
     values = values
       .ToList()
       .Any(x.Value.Contains) 
   });
```

I Expect the output be like `{1,A},{2,D},{4,E}` but actually coming `{1,True},{4,True},{5,True}`

Could some one help me on this.

Comment: Preferably use a `HashSet<string>` instead `String[]`, for O(1) performance

Comment: @mjwills, Thanks for encouraging me. I am first matching the list of string values with dictionary values, if matches then I need to get the matching key and values from the dictionary.

Comment: My expected result be like {1,A},{4,D},{5,E} (Dictionary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, if you want, say, `List<object> == {1, "A", 4, "D", 5, "E"};`

> I Expect the output be like `{1,A,4,D,5,E}`

you can try `Where` to filter out `dict` records and `SelectMany` to flatten them:

```
  Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>() { 
    {1, new "A"},
    {2, new "B"},
    {3, new "c"},
    {4, new "D"},
    {5, new "E"},
  };

  string[] values = new [] {"A", "D", "E"};

  var result = dict
    .Where(pair => values.Contains(pair.Value))
    .SelectMany(pair => new object[] { pair.Key, pair.Value})
    .ToList();

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
  1, A, 4, D, 5, E
```

However, I doubt if you really want such strange data representation. A filtered collection (or dictionary) *without* `SelectMany` is more convenient:

```
  List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> result = dict
    .Where(pair => values.Contains(pair.Value))
    .ToList();

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key}, {pair.Value}")));
```

Or

```
  Dictionary<int, string> result = dict
    .Where(pair => values.Contains(pair.Value))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.value);

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key}, {pair.Value}")));
```

Which produce the same outcome:

```
  1, A, 4, D, 5, E
```

**Edit:** Well, the problem's *changed dramatically*. Now we have

```
  Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, <string>>() { 
    {1, new List<string>() {"A", "B"}},
    {2, new List<string>() {"C", "D"}},
    {3, new List<string>() {"G", "H"}},
    {4, new List<string>() {"E", "F"}},
    {5, new List<string>() {"I", "J"}},
  };

  string[] values = new [] { "A", "D", "E" };
```

And we want filtered `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`:

```
  var result = dict
    .Select(pair => new {
      key = pair.Key,
      value = pair.Value.Intersect(values).ToList()
    })
    .Where(item => item.value.Any())
    .ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} : [{string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}]")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1 : [A]
2 : [D]
4 : [E]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, yes you right I need the result in Dictionary with Same Key and Pair. I will not use the join console or join.

Comment: I am facing error  <code>cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'</code>

Comment: @Nachiappan R: At which line do you have the error?

Comment: values.Contains(**pair.Value**)

Comment: @Nachiappan R: In the question, you've declared `Dictionary<int, string> dict`. Please, check the declaration, isn't it `Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict`? Please, check `string[] values` as well.

Comment: Thanks for catching the error. I declared the Dictionary as Dictionary<int, List<string>> instead of Dictionary<int, string>.

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, Is I need to modify the example right now. But the values I have currently is list of string not string? Please guide or I will create a new question?

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, I modified my example. Please check and suggest me the solution.

Comment: @Nachiappan R: what is the desired outcome, then? `{1,A},{4,D},{5,E}` seems to be *wrong* now, esp. `{4, D}` and `{5, I}` fragments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195614/discussion-between-nachiappan-r-and-dmitry-bychenko).

Comment: Thanks for your contributions and suggestion for my question. Perfectly worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

so, you basically want to select the key-value pairs in the dictionary where the values are in the 'values' array, right?

Something like this:

```
(from kvp in dict
 where values.Contains(kvp.Value)
 select kvp).ToDictionary(key => kvp.Key, value => kvp.Value);
```

Should work, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: As per OP requirement only thing remaining is flatten the result using `SelectMany`

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, 
string>
 { 
  {1, "A"},
  {2, "B"},
  {3, "c"},
  {4, "D"},
  {5, "E"},
 };

 string[] values = new [] 
 {
   "A", "D", "E"
 };
```

Here you want just select dict which contains values of dict.

write linq like this:

```
var query=dict.Where(x=>values.Contains(x.Value));
```

So you get output like below:

```
[1, A]
[4, D]
[5, E]
```

For more please check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tiYtq0)

Comment: I changed my example code. my expected output will be Dictionary<string,List<string>>